# Is there a way to make changing DataFrame faster in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print(index)

        name = row['name']
        new_name = get_name(name)
        row['new_name'] = new_name

        df.loc[index] = row
```

In this piece of code, my testing shows that the last line makes it quite slow, really slow. It basically insert a new column row by row. Maybe I should store all the 'new_name' into a list, and update the df outside of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for processing function for each value of column, it is faster like `iterrows`:

```
df['new_name'] = df['name'].apply(get_name)
```

If want improve performance then is necessary change function if possible, but it depends of function.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_name(x) if x.name == 'name' else x)
```

`.apply` isn't a best practice, however I am not sure there is a better one here.